# What driver do I need for a Radeon Mobility HD 2600 series card?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, video

First of all I have 0 previous experience with any of linux, so I suspect it might be mistake from my part.

But it seems that ubuntu 11.10 are not compatible with my graphic card. I have acer laptop with Radeon Mobility HD 2600 Series graphic card and at moment even linux 2d version is running laggy - mouse reaction delay, overheating.

The installation of graphic driver FGLRX post release update failed with error message guiding me to log file and google search seem to indicate that cause of trouble is that my video card is no longer supported in newest drivers.

The question is weather there is solution (and what it is) or 11.10 is simply not compatible with my old laptop?

Comment: have you tried the open source driver?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [open source driver package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xserver-xorg-video-radeon) [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-radeon] (click on the link to install it).

According to the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man4/radeon.4.html), the package (`xserver-xorg-video-radeon`) should support Radeon Mobility HD 2600.